Is there is a quick way to find out what the row delimiter is for an larger azure blob csv file?
I am using Azure Data Factory.  I am trying to use a Copy Data task.   I set the row delimiter to \r\n but when I go to the mapping tab and import schema I get an error
"Failed to import source schema. The specified row delimiter '' is incorrect. Cannot detect a row after parse 100 MB data.
"
Is there a quick way I can use ADF To find out what the row delimeter is?  I used to a dataflow to create the azure blob csv file and in the data flow sink activity , I set the row delimter to \r\n

As per this Documentation,
The \r\n is supported as row delimiter and it is one of the default value in the dataset while reading the data using copy activity.
So, there is nothing wrong with the row delimiter in your case.

"Failed to import source schema. The specified row delimiter '' is incorrect. Cannot detect a row after parse 100 MB data. "

This error occurs when any one of your row sizes is greater than the default rowSize limit 100MB.
To resolve this error, you need to set the rowSize in the dataset. Go to source Dataset -> Dataset JSON ({ }) -> add the below property in typeproperties.
"MaxRowSize": 2000000


Click on ok and debug the copy activity.
Increase this size as per your data size and check if it works or not.
You can go through the similar ask by @HimanshuSinha-msft.
In the case if you only want to copy this csv file to a target location without changing any columns or mapping, then there no need to use Delimited Text dataset. You can do the same with Binary datasets as source and sink. This doesn't required any mapping and will copy the source csv file to target as it is.
